# Do colonists ever heal by themselves?

Tags: planetbase

All of my workers have been injured mining and I have not yet got a hospital room built, I'm also out of metal so I'm unable to build one, as my injured workers aren't interested in doing much more than standing around.

[image: workers injured]

Do workers eventually recover from such injuries without a hospital or do I need to scrap other buildings to build one/start over?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, colonists will not eventually heal by themselves without medical attention.

The only way for colonists to heal after experiencing trauma or radiation is via the hospital, treated by a medic using medical supplies. If you do not have any medical supplies, medics, or hospital buildings, the injured colonists will just wander around not performing their duties.

Malnutrition can also be treated by medics using medical supplies but you're probably just better off providing a wider variety of meals if you can.

In the instance of certain ailments, for example radiation, the colonist's health will slowly drop over time, eventually leading to death if not treated.